# How to Unset Request Data in CakePHP 3.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've tried to search this but I found no luck.

It says that $request->data will be deprecated in 4.0 and suggesting to use $request->getData() instead.

How do I unset request data when we don't have the option to unset it?

This is useful when logging in or registering with password. When they failed the validation, they have to retype the password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a simple way to do that without even touching the request object, and that is by passing an empty string to the controls `value` option, that way the field will always be empty when it's being rendered:

```
$this->Form->control('password', ['value' => ''])
```

That being said, if there really is the need to unset POST data on the request object (which often times indicates that there's something wrong with what you're doing), you can use `withParsedBody()` to either empty everything:

```
$this->request = $this->request->withParsedBody([]);
```

or write back a partial array:

```
$data = $this->request->getData();
unset($data['password']);
$this->request = $this->request->withParsedBody($data);
```

This may look a little weird, but as already mentioned, the need to unset data on a request object often times indicates a flaw in your application logic.

Comment: This can't be stressed enough: "... the need to unset data on a request object often times indicates a flaw in your application logic."

Comment: Thank you for this and these comments - in our case we needed to only unset one field (a Captcha), mostly for convenience to the end-user, so this seems like an obvious solution.